# Typo in close reason

Tags: bug, status-completed, close-reasons

There's a rather blatant typo in the close reason for identification question**s**:

[image]

The word "question" in the caption should be [pluralized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236746/295232).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the pluralization, I changed the asker version of the post notice - while really cool, unfortunately the `[edit]` link doesn't work in these post notices because it's rendered once and isn't aware of the post it's on, so it can't do the magic it normally would.

[image: The code of the prior post owner guidance that included a markdown error that couldn't be rendered properly for the asker.]

Fortunately, there's a giant edit button directly below the text in the modal, so I've pointed that out in the text instead. If this seems redundant, let me know and I'll fix it.

[image: Modal showing the asker's view of the close post notice for identification questions]

... after re-reading that close notice again, I felt like I could make some improvements, so I've edited the close post notice for both askers and everyone else along with improving the option in the close modal. If anything seems incorrect or off, please blame me (and leave a comment here). The mods had no role in this, don't blame them. :P

[image]